# get object by key then get values from other key same object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects

```
"fields": [
    {
      "label": "Country",
      "name": "country",
      "picklistValues": ["USA", "CAN"],
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "label": "Day",
      "name": "day",
      "picklistValues": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
      "type": "string"
    },
    {...},
  ]
```

Using this code

```
  renderTerritoryMeta() {
      return this.props.territoryMeta.map((territoryField) => {
        return (
          <div className="slds-grid slds-box slds-box--x-small tile">
              {territoryField.label}

          </div>
        );
      });
  }
```

[image]

It's rendering all of the objects in the array. I'd like to get specific objects by key `name` plus the value and then get the `picklistValues` of the same object.

```
// with this array
// get the object by key 'name' & value 'country'
// then with same object get values from key 'pickListValues'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition before the div render
I would try something like that:

```
renderTerritoryMeta() {
      return this.props.territoryMeta.map((territoryField) => {
        const shouldRender = territoryField.name === 'country'
        let pickListValues = []
        if (shouldRender) pickListValues = territoryField.pickListValues
        if (!shouldRender) return null
        return (
          <div className="slds-grid slds-box slds-box--x-small tile">
              {territoryField.label}

          </div>
        );
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short circuit a map when the name = country.

```
render(){
    let fields = [
        {
        "label": "Country",
        "name": "country",
        "picklistValues": ["USA", "CAN"],
        "type": "string"
        },
        {
        "label": "Day",
        "name": "day",
        "picklistValues": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
        "type": "string"
        }
    ]; 

    return(
        <div>
        {
            fields.map(
                ( item, i ) =>
                item.name === 'country'
                &&
                <div key={i}>
                    {
                        item.label
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }            
        </div>
    )
}
```